LiBGDX camera drifts far away from modelinstance after translation and rotation
My camera starts in the position I expect. However, after some time it drifts far away from the red modelinstance! How to keep it position right behind the red modelinstance without drifting far away!
Here is how I initially set up my camera:
    //initial set up of my camera:

 Gdx.input.setCursorCatched(true);
    Gdx.input.setCursorPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);

    camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

 camera.position.set(10f,12f,17.5f);
   
    camera.lookAt(10f,0,10f);        

    camera.up.set(new Vector3(10f,0,10f).Y);
    camera.near = 0.1f;
    camera.far = 300f;     

    camera.update();

Here is how I translate my red model instance: AFTER PRESSING W KEY
BoundingBox bbox0091 = new BoundingBox();
                    ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.calculateBoundingBox(bbox0091);
                    bbox0091.mul(ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform);
                    Vector3 centerV= new Vector3();
                    bbox0091.getCenter(centerV);

 vecyr.set(0,0,0); //clearing vecyr... important
                    mat4_.set(ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform);
                    vecyr.z-=deltatime*LevelOneScreen.playerSpeed;

                    if(Float.compare(Math.abs(centerV.x-10f),0.001f)>0)
                    vecyr.x-=deltatime*centerV.x;
                   
                    mat4_.translate(vecyr);
                    ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform.set(mat4_);
                    ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.calculateTransforms();
                    ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.gameMainPlayerReference.transform.getTranslation(ThreeDWithMultipleScreensGame.playerCurrentPosition);

Here is how I update my camera hoping that it will follow right behind my red model instance:
camera.up.set(0,1,0);
                 
                    Vector3 tmpVector=new Vector3();
                    camera.position.add(tmpVector.set(camera.direction).scl(deltatime*LevelOneScreen.playerSpeed).x,0,
                            tmpVector.set(camera.direction).scl(deltatime*LevelOneScreen.playerSpeed).z);  
                    camera.lookAt(centerV.x,0,centerV.z-7.5f);
                    camera.update();

Here is the picture that show the drifting effect I am talking about:

Notice how the black line gets longer after some time of rotating and translating the red modelinstance How to fix this problem so camera stays always right behind the red model instance?
